# Shared @Input properties on Gradle Plugin tasks, ideally nested config

Tags: groovy, gradle

My gradle plugin generates a number of tasks that have shared configuration. This configuration needs to be marked as @Input, so when it's changed, the task is marked as stale and re-evaluated. I'm finding it challenging to share the config when it should apply to multiple tasks. I'm using avoiding `project.afterEvaluate` to allow incremental compilation. This example is a reduced version of what I currently have:

**Current Plugin Code:**

```
class MyPluginTaskOne extends DefaultTask {
    @Input config = "default"
    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
        // something that depends on config
    }
}

class MyPluginTaskTwo extends DefaultTask {
    @Input config = "default"
    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
        // something that depends on config
    }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
    // blank for now
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.extensions.create("myPluginConfig", MyPluginExtension)
        project.tasks.create(name: 'myPluginTaskOne', type: MyPluginTaskOne) {}
        project.tasks.create(name: 'myPluginTaskTwo', type: MyPluginTaskTwo) {}
    }
}
```

**Current Config:**

Currently the best way I have to share state is the following. This has the problem is that it's error prone and doesn't automatically sharing the setting:

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

// Kludgy way of sharing configuration across two tasks:
def sharedConfig = "SHARED-CONFIG"

myPluginTaskOne {
    config sharedConfig
}

myPluginTaskTwo {
    config sharedConfig
}
```

**Preferred Config:**

What I'd like to do is a configuration something like the following, but with all the benefits of tracking @Input dependencies and up-to-date tests.

```
myPluginConfig {
    config "SHARED-CONFIG"
    // myPluginTaskOne and myPluginTaskTwo both gets automatic
    // 'SHARED-CONFIG' through Gradle
}
```

It appears that you can automatically add dependencies between tasks (see below). Is it possible to configure only the first task and then have that @Input trickle down to the @Input on the second task?

*Let us try removing the task dependencies by relying on how CopySpec.from() evaluates arguments with Project.files(). Gradle can automatically add task dependencies for us. This also adds the output of the generator task as inputs to the zip task.*

From https://gradle.org/feature-spotlight-incremental-builds/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build on Mark's comments.  Here is an example of a property that applies to all tasks and cannot be overridden (config).

```
class MyPluginTaskOne extends DefaultTask {
    @Input String getConfig() { project.myPluginConfig.config }
    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
        // something that depends on config
    }
}

class MyPluginTaskTwo extends DefaultTask {
    @Input String getConfig() { project.myPluginConfig.config }
    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
        // something that depends on config
    }
}

class MyPluginExtension {
    String config
}

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with { 
            extensions.create("myPluginConfig", MyPluginExtension)
            tasks.create(name: 'myPluginTaskOne', type: MyPluginTaskOne) {}
            tasks.create(name: 'myPluginTaskTwo', type: MyPluginTaskTwo) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @bigguy. I successful reworked the j2objc gradle plugin and the Input / Output mechanism is working well.

Answer (score 0):

The most common convention is to use an extension to do this. It looks like you've started to do this. You would then define the property on the extension, then your plugin would read the extension and set the property on all relevant tasks.

```
myPluginConfig {
    sharedConfig 'value'
}
```

In your plugin:

```
def extension = extensions.create("myPluginConfig", MyPluginExtension)
project.afterEvaluate {
    // read prop from `extension` and set prop on tasks
}
```

Comment: I have an Extension setup but it doesn't get get the updated values from the modified extension object during the `.with` call. On the advice of @bigguy, I switched from `.afterEvaluate` to `.with`. I can't remember the issue with `.afterEvaluate` but I think it was about it interfering with the dependencies. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075123/gradle-plugin-best-practices-for-tasks-that-depend-on-extension-objects/27083584#27083584

Comment: There pros/cons with each method. With the method that @bigguy mentions, the property in question is not considered as a task input, therefore is not used for incremental build support (which you are trying to achieve). You can get around this by adding a getter method to each task, which returns the extension property, and is also annotated with `@Input`. The issue with this is the property is effectively read-only, and cannot be set independently for each task (which may be fine). Difference between `with()` and `afterEvaluate()` is the latter is deferred til after the project is configured.

Comment: We're pretty far along with incremental build support. Some config is task specific and then some is shared, so we can mix techniques. Can you outline the getter method for returning the Extension object annotated with `@Input` - this sounds close to what we want. This is for the j2objc gradle script and currently runs over 900 lines. Full script: https://github.com/brunobowden/j2objc-gradle/blob/master/j2objc.gradle

Comment: Basically, working off the example that @bigdaz gave, if you wanted to treat the extension property as input to the task you would add a method to the task like so `@Input String getToolHome() { project.myPluginConfig.toolHome }`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I've tried a number of variations and I can't get something to compile and work correctly. Could you do me the favour of changing your answer to `project.with` style and give a working `@Input String getToolHome() {...}` example. This sounds like it would solve what I'm trying to do.